# 3 Day running sum per user

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that looks like this

```
            time.         user  value
0    2012-01-01  01:01:01    1     1
1    2012-01-02  01:01:01    1     2
2    2012-01-04  01:01:01    2     3
3    2012-01-06  01:01:01    2     1
4    2012-01-07  01:01:01    2     2
5    2012-01-08  01:01:01    2     1
6    2012-01-10  01:01:01    2     2
7    2012-01-13  01:01:01    2     2
8    2012-01-14  01:01:01    3     1
...
```

and I need to know, for each user, if there are any 3 day periods of time where the sum of the values in those 3 days is greater than 5. 1 will represent yes, 0 no. The result should look like this.

```
user  3DS
 1     0
 2     1
 3     0
 ...
```

I know there's some combination of groupby on the user with some type of apply I think. I've found a windowing function that may be useful

```
3_days = timedelta(days=7)
lamba x : sum(df['value'][df['time'] <= x['time'] + 3_days])
```

How do I use pandas to get the second data frame with users and 3 day sum (3DS)?

Comment: whats ur question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you can do a rolling sum over each user.

```
df_total = df.set_index('time').groupby('user').rolling(3).sum()
df_total.groupby(level='user').agg(lambda x: x.max() > 5) * 1
```

Comment: If a user's records are spaced more than a day apart this will not work. Occasionally there will be a user who has a record once every week or month so the window needs to be explicitly 3 days.

Comment: OK, the answer was for three consecutive days. It's been modified to be for 3 records in a row and not tied to calendar days.